# expression Encoder gives an error when try to capture screen

Tags: c#

currently i am developing an error reporting system using c#, in my case i am try to provide user to capture his or her screen when they recreating the problem, in my case i use expression encoder to capture my screen but when i try to run i get the following error

[image]

and this is the full code i used.. please help me to overcome this what is the wrong? when i try the same code @ my office which machines are using windows 7 enterprise edition it's work fine, but when i try to run the same code using my own laptop it gives this error  in my laptop am having windows 7 home premium , and also i try the same code with my friend's laptop which use windows 7 professional.. am i missing any configuration or any reference?

please help

this is the code

```
namespace CAp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CaptureMoni()
    {

        try
        {

            Rectangle _screenRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            _screenCaptureJob = new ScreenCaptureJob();
            _screenCaptureJob.CaptureRectangle = _screenRectangle;
            _screenCaptureJob.ShowFlashingBoundary = true;
            _screenCaptureJob.ScreenCaptureVideoProfile.FrameRate = 20;
            _screenCaptureJob.CaptureMouseCursor = true;

            _screenCaptureJob.OutputScreenCaptureFileName = string.Format(@"C:\test.wmv");
            if (File.Exists(_screenCaptureJob.OutputScreenCaptureFileName))
            {
                File.Delete(_screenCaptureJob.OutputScreenCaptureFileName);
            }
            _screenCaptureJob.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public ScreenCaptureJob _screenCaptureJob { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureMoni();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: BTW: You can click **Ctrl+C** to copy text from an error dialog box to your clipboard. Usually better than posting a screenshot here.

Comment: yes bro, i know it but i did this for better readability since now am in very critical stage since i need to add this feature to my research project, thank you bro!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer yesterday..., It's a matter of my laptops Resolution, since I am using the whole screen capture and expression encoder only support resolutions that can be divided by 4. After changing the resolution to a value that is divisible by 4 as a example (1280X1024), it finally works fine!